# Actionscript workers limitation

Tags: multithreading, actionscript-3, flash, background

I have few questions about workers. 
How can i send to an worker complex objects of my own data types...serialization doesn't work and it is very sad :(
When Adobe is planing to release workers that are able to exchange any data types, starting from primitive and to very complex objects?

Answer (score 0):

[documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html#includeExamplesSummary) suggests otherwise - are you sure that you know how serialisation of custom classes works?

EDIT: I know it is old but if someone need to find ISerializable in flash will fail:) because it is [flash.utils.IExternalizable](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/IExternalizable.html)

Comment: sorry... should be more explicit...I meant data types like Mesh, Geometry for 3D content. It is a very complex data types. Now people explained to me that ISerializable interface should be implemented :)

Comment: yes - that is why I asked if you know how serialisation of custom classes works - in other words the implementation of ISerializable